# Multiple object returns from method not acting as expected

Tags: python, methods, conditional-operator, pyautogui, multiple-return-values

While playing around with `pyautogui` I decided to make a method to limit the position of my cursor depending on the size of my monitor, since I was moving my cursor randomy.

This is what my first attempt looked like.

```
max_x = 10
max_y = 40
def limitXandY(x_arg, y_arg):
    # expected to outputs a tuple of integers with length 2
    return x_arg, y_arg if x_arg < max_x and y_arg < max_y else max_x, max_y
```

When running the code I did not get the expected output.

```
print(limitXandY(5, 19)) # (5, 19, 40) => (x_arg, y_arg, max_y)
x, y = limitXandY(5, 19) # ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
print(limitXandY(50, 100)) # (50, 10, 40) => (x_arg, max_x, max_y)
x, y = limitXandY(50, 100) # ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

As you can see above, my method returns a tuple of length 3 instead of 2. If the ternary operator goes in the if statement, I get the desired output plus last value of the else statement and if the operator returns in the else statement, I get the first value of the if statement as the first value of the methods output tuple.

I have found a work around using parentheses, but this doesn't really satisfy me and I would like to understand why this ternary operator acts like this.

```
def correctedLimitXandY(x_arg, y_arg):
    # expected to output a tuple of tuple with length 1
    # inner tuple should containt integers of length 2
    return (x_arg, y_arg) if x_arg < max_x and y_arg < max_y else (max_x, max_y)

print(correctedLimitXandY(5, 19)) # (5, 19) => (x_arg, y_arg)
x, y = correctedLimitXandY(5, 19) # no error
print(correctedLimitXandY(50, 100)) # (10, 40) => (max_x, max_y)
x, y = correctedLimitXandY(50, 100) # no error
```

Any explanations would be a help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any explanations would be a help!

While ternaries have a fairly low precedence, they're still considered an operator and thus binding "tighter" than tuple literal, much like e.g.

```
a+b,c+d
```

is interpreted as

```
(a + b), (c + d)
```

not

```
a + (b, c) + d
```

When you write

```
x_arg, y_arg if x_arg < max_x and y_arg < max_y else max_x, max_y
```

Python will first "resolve" `<`, then `and`, then `if/else`, and only after that does it resolve the tuples, so the result is:

```
x_arg, (y_arg if ((x_arg < max_x) and (y_arg < max_y)) else max_x), max_y
```

You can infer this from [the full language grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), specifically:

```
expressions:
    | expression (',' expression )+ [','] 
    | expression ',' 
    | expression

expression:
    | disjunction 'if' disjunction 'else' expression 
    | disjunction
    | lambdef
```

Here you can see that an `expressions` is a comma-separated sequence of `expression`, and each `expression` can be a ternary (`if/else`), therefore the language "resolves" ternaries (the inner structure) first.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear and fast response, it makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet of code is equivalent to this:

```
return x_arg, (y_arg if x_arg < max_x and y_arg < max_y else max_x), max_y
```

Which is a tuple of three elements.

This has to do with the fact that the interpreter first reaches the comma than the conditional. That is: it first decides is interpreting a tuple and then finds a conditional expression.